# Explanation of update statement with if() function

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sql-update

Can anyone please help me with this query? I don't understand what this `IF` is doing.

```
UPDATE yob_users 
     SET money = money + IF(account='premium',$premiumclick,$click), 
         visits = CONVERT(visits,UNSIGNED) + 1 
WHERE username='$user'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is

```
IF(<boolean expression>, <then>, <else>)
```

Your query updates every row with a given username and adds to each row the amount of `$premiumclick` if in the same row `account` is equal to `"premium"`. Otherwise it adds the amount of `$click`. It also increments visits in each row.

Most probably you have a signed [integer column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html) visits. This allows values between -2147483648 2147483647. An unsigned integer allow values between 0 and 4294967295. But if you convert it, you can increment it, yes, but the assignment will fail, if the value is too large for the signed visits column.

Any more questions?